# Why can't I configure my Pip3 installation

Tags: python, pip

I've followed this website guide (https://vgkits.org/blog/pip3-config-howto/)  to install pip3, but when I came to the step that needs me to configure my Pip3 installation, the cmd terminal shows invalid syntax.

```py
C:\Windows\System32>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> pip3 install --user pybin
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip3 install --user pybin
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you are not supossed to run this command in your python shell. Run it outside of python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1):

You are running this command in the Python shell, you should instead run it the normal command prompt window.

Because you are on Windows, use Win + R to open run window, and type in cmd to open the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the code from the Python shell when you need to run it from the command line. If you'd like to install a package from the Python shell, this will work:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'PACKAGE'])
```